# Pasar un string que contiene un array a HashMap

Tags: java, json, string, hashmap, jackson

Quiero convertir un String que contiene un Json a Hashmap usando Jackson. El problema es que el Json está dentro de un array (creo que el problema es ese) por lo que jackson no detecta bien el json y falla.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(reportJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
//https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/ <-- referencia
```

En el que reportJson es lo siguiente (voy a simplificarlo mucho porque es demasiado grande):

```
[{
    "line": 1,
    "elements": [{
        "start_timestamp": "2020-03-13T12:14:35.340Z",
        "before": [{
            "result": {
                "error_message": "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: asdfasdf",
                "duration": 35995000000,
                "status": "failed"
            },
            "match": {
                "location": "Cucumber.Tarragona.Integrados.Hooks.GeneralHooks.setup(io.cucumber.java.Scenario)"
            }
        }],
        "line": 4,
        "name": "Alta escala",
        "description": "",
        "id": "alta-escala;alta-escala",
        "after": [{
            "embeddings": [{
                "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAA",
                "Something": "more..."
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

He comprobado que el json sea válido, y lo es. El error que lanza es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1219)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmpty(StdDeserializer.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4218)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3197)
    at TestlinkAPI.TestlinkApiDemo.TestLinkConnector.executeKatalonSpecificTestCase(TestLinkConnector.java:605)
    at TestlinkAPI.TestlinkApiDemo.TestLinkConnector.main(TestLinkConnector.java:218)
```

No quiero crear las clases java para convertir el json a un objeto de java porque el json es muy complejo y tendría que crear demasiadas clases, quiero convertirlo a HashMap para poder acceder a los valores deseados introduciendo las claves oportunas.

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, debes traducir tu pregunta o terminará cerrada.

Comment: Ostras, antes no era así, para que la mayoría nos entendiera todo en inglés jajaj disculpa, ahora mismo voy.

Comment: En tu pregunta está demás la parte de inglés, considera editar y eliminar esa parte.

Comment: Vale... Pero pienso que la comunidad inglesa es más grande que la española, qué mejor que tenerlo en varios idiomas. En fin, gracias por las sugerencias, ahora lo edito.

Comment: Puedes también hacer tu pregunta en el sitio de SO en inglés. Son comunidades diferentes.

Comment: Ni idea de cómo hacerlo xD

Comment: El error `out of START_ARRAY token` indica claramente que tu JSON es inválido o erróneo. En cuanto  a esto que dices: *No quiero crear las clases java para convertir el json a un objeto de java porque el json es muy complejo y tendría que crear demasiadas clases*. Debería ser precisamente lo contrario. Mientras más complejo sea el caso, más deberías organizar el código, creando las clases que haga falta. Luego mapeas a un objeto y usas los métodos de las clases para obtener la información. Además hay herramientas gratuitas y en línea que te crean las clases pegando el JSON.

Comment: Debería ser así si fuera a usarlo mucho, pero solo quiero obtener de él un atributo una sola vez en todo el código, para saber si un test ha ido bien o no por lo que me parece un poco excesivo crear toodas esas clases tan sólo para esa comprobación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado dos soluciones.

La primera, quito el primer y último carácter del string para que deje de ser un array (sé con certeza que el array siempre va a tener sólo un objeto). De esta manera, ya se pasa correctamente al Map:

`Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(reportJson.substring(1,reportJson.length()-1), Map.class); <-- Ahora`

`Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(reportJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {}); <-- Antes`

Otra manera es usando JsonPath, con el que podemos acceder directamente a la propiedad que queramos:

`String msg = JsonPath.read(reportJson, "$.[0].elements.[0].before.[0].result.error_message");`

msg contendría lo siguiente:

`"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: asdfasdf"`

He visto alguna más pero estas dos son las que más sencillas me han parecido.

Answer (score 0):

el error es que le estas diciendo que es un objeto{} y lo que le llega es el array[]

Te dejo las clases necesarias para que funcione correctamente.

Pase el json al JavaClass y te dejo el ejemplo de como manipular el objecto java para acceder a sus propiedades
Clase After
    package jackson;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "embeddings"
})
public class After implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("embeddings")
    private List<Embedding> embeddings = new ArrayList<Embedding>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 4778244079667215173L;

    @JsonProperty("embeddings")
    public List<Embedding> getEmbeddings() {
        return embeddings;
    }

    @JsonProperty("embeddings")
    public void setEmbeddings(List<Embedding> embeddings) {
        this.embeddings = embeddings;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Clase Before

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "result",
    "match"
})
public class Before implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("result")
    private Result result;
    @JsonProperty("match")
    private Match match;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 8550764990741479357L;

    @JsonProperty("result")
    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @JsonProperty("result")
    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @JsonProperty("match")
    public Match getMatch() {
        return match;
    }

    @JsonProperty("match")
    public void setMatch(Match match) {
        this.match = match;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Clase Element

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "start_timestamp",
    "before",
    "line",
    "name",
    "description",
    "id",
    "after"
})
public class Element implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("start_timestamp")
    private String startTimestamp;
    @JsonProperty("before")
    private List<Before> before = new ArrayList<Before>();
    @JsonProperty("line")
    private String line;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("after")
    private List<After> after = new ArrayList<After>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -748678453076271504L;

    @JsonProperty("start_timestamp")
    public String getStartTimestamp() {
        return startTimestamp;
    }

    @JsonProperty("start_timestamp")
    public void setStartTimestamp(String startTimestamp) {
        this.startTimestamp = startTimestamp;
    }

    @JsonProperty("before")
    public List<Before> getBefore() {
        return before;
    }

    @JsonProperty("before")
    public void setBefore(List<Before> before) {
        this.before = before;
    }

    @JsonProperty("line")
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    @JsonProperty("line")
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("after")
    public List<After> getAfter() {
        return after;
    }

    @JsonProperty("after")
    public void setAfter(List<After> after) {
        this.after = after;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Clase Embedding

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "data",
    "Something"
})
public class Embedding implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String data;
    @JsonProperty("Something")
    private String something;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 4536695558299274576L;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Something")
    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Something")
    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Clase Jackson

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "line",
    "elements"
})
public class Jackson implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("line")
    private String line;
    @JsonProperty("elements")
    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -5004687646036732347L;

    @JsonProperty("line")
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    @JsonProperty("line")
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    @JsonProperty("elements")
    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    @JsonProperty("elements")
    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Clase Match

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "location"
})
public class Match implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 4690812775863010954L;

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Clase Result

```
package jackson;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "location"
})
public class Match implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 4690812775863010954L;

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Y para testearlo hice el main

```
package jackson;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String reportJson = "[{\"line\":1,\"elements\":[{\"start_timestamp\":\"2020-03-13T12:14:35.340Z\",\"before\":[{\"result\":{\"error_message\":\"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: asdfasdf\",\"duration\":35995000000,\"status\":\"failed\"},\"match\":{\"location\":\"Cucumber.Tarragona.Integrados.Hooks.GeneralHooks.setup(io.cucumber.java.Scenario)\"}}],\"line\":4,\"name\":\"Alta escala\",\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"alta-escala;alta-escala\",\"after\":[{\"embeddings\":[{\"data\":\"iVBORw0KGgoAAA\",\"Something\":\"more...\"}]}]}]}]";
        Reader reader = new StringReader(reportJson);
        try {
            // JSON file to Java object
            //Jackson staff = mapper.readValue(reportJson, Jackson.class);
            Jackson[] jsonObj = mapper.readValue(reportJson, Jackson[].class);

            List<Jackson> list = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(reportJson, Jackson[].class));

            String prettyStaff1 = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObj);
            System.out.println(prettyStaff1);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");

            list.stream().forEach(e->{
                e.getElements().stream().forEach(r->System.out.print(r.getStartTimestamp()));
            });

        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
[ {
  "line" : "1",
  "elements" : [ {
    "start_timestamp" : "2020-03-13T12:14:35.340Z",
    "before" : [ {
      "result" : {
        "error_message" : "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: asdfasdf",
        "duration" : "35995000000",
        "status" : "failed"
      },
      "match" : {
        "location" : "Cucumber.Tarragona.Integrados.Hooks.GeneralHooks.setup(io.cucumber.java.Scenario)"
      }
    } ],
    "line" : "4",
    "name" : "Alta escala",
    "description" : "",
    "id" : "alta-escala;alta-escala",
    "after" : [ {
      "embeddings" : [ {
        "data" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAA",
        "Something" : "more..."
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
} ]
-------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-13T12:14:35.340Z
```

Puedes notar que en el main en esta parte:

```
Jackson[] jsonObj = mapper.readValue(reportJson, Jackson[].class);
```

Si haces

```
Jackson jsonObj = mapper.readValue(reportJson, Jackson.class);
```

Lanzara la excepción que mencionas **out of START_ARRAY token**

Una vez que tengas  **jsonObj** eso lo podrás manipular a lo que mejor te parezca.

Comment: No me gustaría crear una clase de java por cada elemento que tenga el json, lo he simplificado mucho para poner un ejemplo en esta pregunta pero lo que llega realmente es inmenso y sólo lo necesito para obtener un único parámetro de todo el JSON, en una parte específica de mi código, por lo que crear absolutamente todas las clases pienso que daría al proyecto mucho más complejidad de la que necesita. Pretendo es convertir toda esa estructura a HashMap (si es que se puede) para poder acceder así a la propiedad que quiero. El json es el resultado de un test, solo quiero saber si ha ido bien o no

Comment: De todas maneras, tu respuesta sé que es la manera correcta de hacerlo y que así funcionaría. Muchas gracias.